# determining cell type based on image loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have two different UITableViewCell type, say A and B. A is being used if based on the image URL data source I have, the image loads and B is being used if the image doesn't load. How can I do this? The issue is that at cellForRowAtIndexPath I don't know whether the image loads or not. So then I'd probably have to load all of the image first. Is there another way?

There is a Story object that I am using which has an imageURL. The data source of the tableview is an array of Story.

Comment: How are you differentiating between an image loading or not? Is there a model object with a flag? If yes, use that flag to differentiate it in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: @ACB I can add a flag in the model object. But then to determine the value of this flag, I'd had to load the image first.. so basically I am doing image resizing/cropping on the backend. If the image can be resized according to backend's algorithm then it returns the image, in this case the image loads.. but if the image failed.. then in this case I'd want to use cell B. In this case, the flag I am using is a UIImage, if UIImage exists then I use cell A otherwise I use B.

Comment: So have your method that trys to create image A return nil if it can't. Then check if what is returned is nil or not. ---nevermind, I reread your post. Is the image loaded with a url? do you want to check if the image exists at that url?

Comment: the issue is that it's an expensive operation, such that you'll have to load all the image returned from backend.. say backend returns 25 stories then basically I will try to load 25 image.

Comment: Do it asynchronously. I'll post an answer using UIImageView+Afnetworking

Comment: @mkral I know how to do it using AFNetworking, are you suggesting to download the image on the Story data model?

Comment: @adit, So cant you just add a new flag in story object which says if the image is being downloaded or downloaded etc..? Instead of checking using `image!=nil`, you can use `if (imageIsGettingDownloaded) { show this} else { show the other one }`

Comment: okay, so the problem with this is a race condition.. because the first  - third image hasn't been downloaded and cellForRowAtIndexPath is called first.. which results in it to use cell B (no image), while it has an image actually

Comment: Why don't you use afnetworking's UIImageView category and just set the image to load from url with a placeholder image? That will keep the appearance of what you need and load when the image is available and not tie up the main thread.

Comment: the issue is that when the image exists.. the title of the story is on the top and if the image doesn't exist the title is then at the bottom.. if say I am loading the image, and it turns out the image doesn't exist.. you'll see that title label shifts from the top to the bottom, which is annoying

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a.com/image.png"];

UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
[imageview setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png" ] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    NSLog(@"Handle SUCCESS");
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Handle FAILURE");    }];
```